# random array in for loop PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

Currently working on a.. lets say random word generator. I think I made it already work, but unfortunately for loop returns the same value as the first one.

`

```
$ones = array("One.", "Two.", "Three.", "Four.", "Five.", "Six.", "Seven.", "Eight.", "Nine.", "Ten.");
$one_rand = array_rand($ones, 2);
$one = $ones[$one_rand[0]];

$twos = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");
$two_rand = array_rand($twos, 2);
$two = $twos[$two_rand[0]];

$ends = array(".a", ".b", ".c", ".d", ".e", ".g", ".h", ".i", ".j");
$end_rand = array_rand($ends, 2);
$end = $ends[$end_rand[0]];



$return = $one . $two . $end;



for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
    echo $return . "<br>";
}
```

`

This code returns(for example):

```
Three.4.b <br>
Three.4.b <br>
Three.4.b <br>
Three.4.b <br>
Three.4.b <br>
```

But I want it to be random after every `" < br > "`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Within the loop you're just repeatedly echoing the same fixed variable which was defined before the loop started. Within 
the loop  nothing changes from one iteration to the next. It sounds like actually your whole code needs to be within the loop so it generates new random  variables on every iteration.

Comment: Wow, that was easy. Dumb me. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

so the issue is that you assign the values to $one, $two, $three once, that means it will not change when you create a loop after that, what you need to do is loop the value assignment something like:

```
$ones = array("One.", "Two.", "Three.", "Four.", "Five.", "Six.", "Seven.", "Eight.", "Nine.", "Ten.");
$twos = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");
$ends = array(".a", ".b", ".c", ".d", ".e", ".g", ".h", ".i", ".j");

for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
    $one_rand = array_rand($ones, 2);
    $one = $ones[$one_rand[0]];
    $two_rand = array_rand($twos, 2);
    $two = $twos[$two_rand[0]];
    $end_rand = array_rand($ends, 2);
    $end = $ends[$end_rand[0]];
    $return = $one . $two . $end;

    echo $return . "<br>";
}
```

But that means you will need to call array_rand for each loop, which is pretty bad, a better choice would be to just randomize the array first and then you can use the loop index to choose the values, which will still be random but faster, something like:

```
$ones = array("One.", "Two.", "Three.", "Four.", "Five.", "Six.", "Seven.", "Eight.", "Nine.", "Ten.");
$twos = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");
$ends = array(".a", ".b", ".c", ".d", ".e", ".g", ".h", ".i", ".j");
// I have used shuffle instead of array_rand, because for array_rand you 
// need to specify the number of items returned, which is not really dynamic
shuffle($ones);
shuffle($twos);
shuffle($ends);

for ($x = 1; $x <= 5; $x++) {
    echo $ones[$x] . $two[$x] . $end[$x] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Not going to lie, I was today years old when I found out shuffle() exists. Thank you, that's a solid solution to my problem.